# I want only those EmployeeId whose ComplainStatus has "In Progress" and "Resolved" that is whose ComplainId=2 and 6 means no other Employee

Tags: sql-server, database

basically I want turn around time for those employee whose complain were in progress and resolved not those whose complain are still in progress and not resolved or any other case.

my tables are:

```
DevEmployee:
EmployeeId EmployeeName
1          Alex
2          Samson
3          Harry
4          Ronney
5          Stoinis
6          Joanna
7          Nicole
8          Fergusion
```

DevComplain:

```
ComplainId Complainstatus
1          Open
2          In Progress
3          On Hold
4          Deferred
5          Escalate
6          Resolved
```

DevEmployeeDetail:

```
EmployeeId ComplainId ComplainCreatedDate
1          1          2019-01-18 00:00:00.000
1          2          2019-01-20 10:34:09.000
1          3          2119-01-20 05:14:01.110
2          1          2019-01-10 05:14:01.110
2          2          2019-01-11 08:34:01.000
2          3          2019-01-12 01:05:00.000
2          2          2019-01-13 03:07:20.700
2          4          2019-01-14 11:19:20.110
2          2          2019-01-15 12:09:10.110
2          6          2019-01-16 02:49:01.010
3          1          2019-04-22 10:06:12.100

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @j INT
DECLARE @lt INT
DECLARE @OnHold DATETIME
DECLARE @OnDeferred DATETIME
DECLARE @OnOpen DATETIME
DECLARE @OnProgress DATETIME
DECLARE @OnEscalate DATETIME
DECLARE @allcount INT
DECLARE @Employee INT
DECLARE @complain INT
DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @time INT = 0
DECLARE @resdate DATETIME
DECLARE @progdate DATETIME
DECLARE @Eid INT
DECLARE @diff DECIMAL

SET @i = 1
SET @lt = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (
            SELECT MAX(ComplainCreatedDate) AS ResolveTime
                ,EmployeeId
            FROM DevEmployeeDetail
            WHERE complainId = 6
            GROUP BY EmployeeId
            ) a
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MIN(ComplainCreatedDate) AS InProgressTime
                ,EmployeeId
            FROM DevEmployeeDetail
            WHERE complainId = 2
            GROUP BY EmployeeId
            ) b ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
        )

WHILE @i <= @lt
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (@i) @eid = a.EmployeeId
        ,@resdate = a.ResolveTime
        ,@progdate = b.InProgressTime
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(ComplainCreatedDate) AS ResolveTime
            ,EmployeeId
        FROM DevEmployeeDetail
        WHERE complainId = 6
        GROUP BY EmployeeId
        ) a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(ComplainCreatedDate) AS InProgressTime
            ,EmployeeId
        FROM DevEmployeeDetail
        WHERE complainId = 2
        GROUP BY EmployeeId
        ) b ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId

    SET @j = 1
    SET @allcount = (
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM DevEmployeeDetail
            WHERE @eid = EmployeeId
                AND ComplainCreatedDate > @progdate
                AND ComplainCreatedDate < @resdate
            )

    WHILE @j <= @allcount
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP (@j) @Employee = EmployeeId
            ,@complain = complainId
            ,@date = ComplainCreatedDate
        FROM DevEmployeeDetail
        WHERE @eid = EmployeeId
            AND ComplainCreatedDate > @progdate
            AND ComplainCreatedDate < @resdate

        SET @j = @j + 1

        IF @complain = 3
        BEGIN
            SET @OnHold = @date
        END

        IF @complain = 4
        BEGIN
            SET @OnDeferred = @date
        END

        IF @complain = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @OnOpen = @date
        END

        IF @complain = 5
        BEGIN
            SET @OnEscalate = @date
        END

        IF @complain = 2
        BEGIN
            SET @OnProgress = @date
        END

        SELECT @Employee EmployeeId
            ,@progdate InProgressDate
            ,@resdate ResolvedDate
            ,datediff(second, @progdate, @resdate) diff
            ,@complain STATUS
            ,@OnHold OnHold
            ,@OnDeferred OnDeferred
            ,@OnOpen OnOpen
            ,@OnEscalate OnEscalate
            ,@OnProgress OnProgress

        SET @OnDeferred = NULL
        SET @OnHold = NULL
        SET @OnOpen = NULL
        SET @OnProgress = NULL
        SET @OnEscalate = NULL
    END

    SET @i = @i + 1

    SELECT @Eid EmployeeId
        ,@progdate InProgressDate
        ,@resdate ResolvedDate
        ,@complain STATUS
        ,@OnHold OnHold
        ,@OnDeferred OnDeferred
        ,@OnOpen OnOpen
        ,@OnEscalate OnEscalate
        ,@OnProgress OnProgress
END;
```

I want only those EmployeeId whose ComplainStatus has "In Progress" and "Resolved" that is whose ComplainId=2 and 6 means no other Employee. After getting these employee I want to calculate the turnaround time of those employee.

I have tried this but still could not get desire answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  First off, good job for including sample data in your question.  Based on your procedure I'm going to guess that you come from a procedural coding background - am I right?  It would be very helpful to have the output that your code currently gives you for the sample data you provided, and an example of the output that you want.

Comment: Yes I have procedural coding background. my output are generating multiple columns so that it cannot be selected, but I can explain your confusing point.

Comment: At the very least, you need to update your question to include the desired output based on the sample data you provided.  Otherwise no-one here will know what we're trying to accomplish.  Remember - you're the only one who's been working on this until now.

Comment: A couple of things before getting to what you want: I would change some names: DevComplain to DevComplainStatus, CompainId to ComplainStatusId, DevEmployeeDetail to  DevEmployeeComplainDetail to actually reflect what you have. Then, I would add an actual ComplainId that links all the records for a particular employee complain in the DevEmployeeComplainDetail table. Once you have this in place you can query for how long each complain took to resolve. Without this, if an employee has overlapping complains that get resolved, you are not guaranteed to get the right times for each one.

Comment: Your code is already calculating the time: `datediff(second, @progdate, @resdate) diff`. What is not working?

Comment: the diff I'm getting is the time which employeecomplain take time in process means inprogress to resolved time but I want to minus all time like onhold, deferred, escalate from this diff of each employee if these time are getting occurred like this: TAT=Diff-(onHold,deferrred,escalate)

Comment: This may be of help: https://bertwagner.com/2019/03/12/gaps-and-islands/